# Unity: Assertion failed: Assertion failed on expression: 'CompareApproximately(det, 1.0F, .005f)'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting the following errors after 
I am using the [Cinemachine](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/cinemachine-79898) asset in my game. I am pausing the game using standard `Time.timeScale = 0`. But when I unpause the game using `Time.timeScale = 1` I get the following errors. As per [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/assertion-failed-with-unity-2017-2-0b8-64-bit.490938/), these errors were fixed in version 2017.2, my version is 2018.1.3f1 and I am still getting these errors.

```
Assertion failed: Assertion failed on expression: 'CompareApproximately(det, 1.0F, .005f)'
UnityEngine.Quaternion:FromToRotation(Vector3, Vector3)
Cinemachine.Utility.PositionPredictor:PredictPosition(Single) (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Core/Predictor.cs:64)
Cinemachine.CinemachineFramingTransposer:MutateCameraState(CameraState&, Single) (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Components/CinemachineFramingTransposer.cs:318)
Cinemachine.CinemachineVirtualCamera:CalculateNewState(Vector3, Single) (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Behaviours/CinemachineVirtualCamera.cs:426)
Cinemachine.CinemachineVirtualCamera:UpdateCameraState(Vector3, Single) (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Behaviours/CinemachineVirtualCamera.cs:128)
Cinemachine.CinemachineCore:UpdateVirtualCamera(ICinemachineCamera, Vector3, Single) (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Core/CinemachineCore.cs:237)
Cinemachine.CinemachineCore:UpdateAllActiveVirtualCameras(Vector3, Single) (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Core/CinemachineCore.cs:165)
Cinemachine.CinemachineBrain:UpdateVirtualCameras(UpdateFilter, Single) (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Behaviours/CinemachineBrain.cs:445)
Cinemachine.CinemachineBrain:LateUpdate() (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Behaviours/CinemachineBrain.cs:399)

Assertion failed: Assertion failed on expression: 'fRoot >= Vector3f::epsilon'
UnityEngine.Quaternion:FromToRotation(Vector3, Vector3)
Cinemachine.Utility.PositionPredictor:PredictPosition(Single) (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Core/Predictor.cs:64)
Cinemachine.CinemachineFramingTransposer:MutateCameraState(CameraState&, Single) (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Components/CinemachineFramingTransposer.cs:318)
Cinemachine.CinemachineVirtualCamera:CalculateNewState(Vector3, Single) (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Behaviours/CinemachineVirtualCamera.cs:426)
Cinemachine.CinemachineVirtualCamera:UpdateCameraState(Vector3, Single) (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Behaviours/CinemachineVirtualCamera.cs:128)
Cinemachine.CinemachineCore:UpdateVirtualCamera(ICinemachineCamera, Vector3, Single) (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Core/CinemachineCore.cs:237)
Cinemachine.CinemachineCore:UpdateAllActiveVirtualCameras(Vector3, Single) (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Core/CinemachineCore.cs:165)
Cinemachine.CinemachineBrain:UpdateVirtualCameras(UpdateFilter, Single) (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Behaviours/CinemachineBrain.cs:445)
Cinemachine.CinemachineBrain:LateUpdate() (at Assets/Cinemachine/Base/Runtime/Behaviours/CinemachineBrain.cs:399)
```

My console gets flooded with these errors every time I unpause the game and this is also causing the animations not to play properly.

Comment: A silly question but have you tried to slow the game so much it's almost paused? Let's say `Time.timeScale = 0.001f` and see if this still happens? (I believe it will NOT, but who knows.)

Comment: Also, take a look at this: https://forum.unity.com/threads/assertion-failed-with-unity-2017-2-0b8-64-bit.490938/ which then, lead to this https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/transform-assertion-failed-on-expression-compareapproximately-det-1-dot-0f-005f-when-scaling-system-to-0-on-at-least-2-axes which is a bug that is supposed to be fixed on 2017.2.0f3.

Comment: no it didn't happen when i change it to 0.001f, and yes i saw that bug and have posted my logs in there as well.

Comment: @VitorFigueredo I can't set the timescale to 0.0001f instead of 0f to fix this.

Comment: download Unity 2018.1.6f1. That could solve your issue